# Javascript code freezes screen for set amount of time

Tags: javascript, time, freeze

I'm attempting with the following code to

1. Display the results of a card game,
2. Wait for 3 seconds while displaying a countdown and then,
3. Reload the screen.

   ```
   //Display results, at least that was the idea.
   for(var player = 0; player < players.length; player++)
   {
       resultString = players[player][6]
       if (result == null) { resultString += ", its a tie."; }
       else
       {
           resultString += (player == 0 ? ", you" : ", cassino") +
           (player == result ? (player == 0 ? " win" : " wins") :
           (player == 0 ? " lose" : " loses"));
       document.getElementById(player == 0 ? "player" : "casino").
       childNodes[0].nodeValue = resultString;
       }
       showHand(players[player]);
   }

   //Lag for 3 seconds while displaying a countdown. At least it lags alright.
   var time = new Date().getTime();
   while (((time / 1000) + 3) - (new Date().getTime() / 1000 ) > 0)
   {
       document.getElementById("call").childNodes[0].nodeValue = "Next round in "
       + Math.ceil(((time / 1000) + 3) - (new Date().getTime() / 1000 ))
       .toFixed(0);
   }
   //Reload screen. Working fine.
   dealHands();
   }
   ```

The problem is that by running this code the screen instead *freezes* for 3 seconds before loading the reloading the screen, even though console.log points out no problems with the values to be displayed in the "//Display results" section of the program. In fact, if I comment the portion *after* the comment "//Lag for 3 seconds..." the results are displayed as intended.
Is there some property of .time() that I'm unaware of that is overriding the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display countdown after 3 seconds, you can put your code to reload the screen in a function and call that function using `window.setTimeout` which wouldn't freeze the window and function gets invoked after the amount of time you specify there.

And for the countdown display, you can use `window.setInterval`.